# "Fatal Error: Call to undefined function" even though the function is definitely defined

Tags: php

This is my first real foray into PHP and I am struggling to understand why an error message is appearing. I have defined a function and yet I am being told I have not done so.

I have tried changing the name of the function andchanging the order the functions appear in the class (which I knew wouldn't make a difference), but I cannot think of anything else I could do to make this work. The code looks absolutely fine to me, and the error message doesn't give much to work with.

```
<?php

class PinNumberGenerator {

private $pins;
private $disallowedPins = array(0000,1111,2222,3333,4444,5555,6666,7777,8888,9999,1234,5678,2468); // Obvious pins

function __construct($amount) {
    $pins = $this->createPinsArray($amount);
}

function generatePin() {
    return rand(0,9).rand(0,9).rand(0,9).rand(0,9);
}

private function createPinsArray($amount) {

    $currentPin;
    $pinsArray = array();

    while(count($pinsArray) < $amount) {

        $currentPin = generatePin();

        if (in_array($currentPin, $disallowedPins)) {
            continue;
        } else {
            $pinsArray[] = $currentPin;
        }
    }

    return $pinsArray;
}

public function getPins() {

    foreach($pin as $pins) {
    echo $pin . "<br>";
    }

}
}

$pins = new PinNumberGenerator(10);
$pins->getPins();

?>
```

Comment: What function is undefined? That would help to know.

Comment: If PHP tells you something is undefined, you definitely didn't define it.

Comment: It was the generatePin function

Comment: and it *was* defined, it wasn't being accessed correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`generatePin()` is an instance method of a class. It must be references with `$this`. Change:

```
$currentPin = generatePin();
```

to:

```
$currentPin = $this->generatePin();
```

Do the same for all references to `$pins`.

Change:

```
$pins = $this->createPinsArray($amount);
```

to:

```
$this->pins = $this->createPinsArray($amount);
```

And change:

```
foreach($pin as $pins) {
```

to:

```
foreach($this->pins as $pin) {
```

And finally, change:

```
if (in_array($currentPin, $disallowedPins)) {
```

to

```
if (in_array($currentPin, $this->disallowedPins)) {
```

All class members need to be referenced with `$this`.

Comment: Assuming it is part of that class. The way this code is written we don't know that.

Comment: Yes we do. It's just not indented. But it's definitely in the `PinNumberGenerator` class.

Comment: It's indented in Notepad++, just not here. It seems it didn't paste well, sorry.

Comment: I now see the entire class declaration. I wonder if they did an edit after I read the question?

Comment: Thank you Asaph, that's put me on the right track! Making that change caused about 15 other errors to come up, but that's definitely more to work with :D

Comment: @LegendEater Glad to this answer was helpful. Please mark it correct by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: `foreach($this->pins as $pin) {` probably.

Comment: It's saying I have to do it in 5 minutes. You're obviously too quick for SO.
While I have you, it's now saying disallowedPins is undefined, even though I have used $this-> to reference it in my createPinsArray function. Can you see any reason that might be?

Edit: I had $this->$disallowedPins and not $this->disallowedPins. I'll get there!

Comment: @AbraCadaver Good catch. Fixed.

Comment: Fixed that too, AbraCadaver. Well spotted. Seems there are more problems with this than I initially thought

Answer (score 0):

All methods inside a class should be accessed using $this

so inside your class PinNumberGenerator you should access generatePin() function 
using $this

$this->generatePin();